# What is the right exponent $s$ such that $ n_1^p + n_2^q\geq(n_1 + n_2)^s$ holds?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, elementary-number-theory

Let $n_1, n_2$ be two real positive number and consider $p, q>1$. I am looking for a real number $s$ such that the following inequality holds:
$$ n_1^p + n_2^q\geq(n_1 + n_2)^s.$$
I was thinking about $s=\min(p, q)$, but the inequality does not work for $0< n_1, n_2<1$. Could anyone please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It doesn't exist, you need $s\geq \max(p, q) $, you also need $s\leq \min(p, q) $ so we need $p=q=s$ but the inequality then isn't satisfied for any $n_1,n_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ and $q$ be real numbers greater than $1$, and suppose $s$ satisfies
$$n_1^p+n_2^q\geq(n_1+n_2)^s,$$
for all positive real numbers $n_1$ and $n_2$. As $n_2$ tends to $0$ we see that
$$\lim_{n_2\to0}(n_1^p+n_2^q)=n_1^p\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\lim_{n_2\to0}(n_1+n_2)^s=n_1^s,$$
from which it follows that $n_1^p\geq n_1^s$ for every positive real number $n_1$. In particular, for $n_1=2$ we get $2^p\geq2^s$ and hence $p\geq s$, and for $n_1=2^{-1}$ we get $2^{-p}\geq2^{-s}$ and hence $p\leq s$. This shows that $s=p$, and by symmetry also $s=q$. But then
$$(n_1+n_2)^s>n_1^s+n_2^s,$$
because $s>1$, a contradiction. Hence no such number $s$ exists.